# Electron is building empty app after context isolation set to false

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron, electron-packager

I'm facing a weird problem.
I need to set context isolation to false to parse big excel files because with IPC it takes 2x more ram than it should to.
I noticed that when I use built in modules into node like fs for example, app builds just fine, but whenever I try to add module that was installed by me for example node-xlsx or read-excel-file/node then after package the app opens completely empty window even though while running it in vscode with npm start it works ok... I don't understad what is happening.
My imports in renderer :
[image]

I tried importing it without default as well :

Comment: did you tried to use module syntax like `import fs from 'fs'` ? window.require looks like runtime require, so it would not included to bundle.

Comment: @zb' you were right. I had to find library that allow me to import it instead of requiring it. So I found XLSX library , changed code a little bit and everything works !!!